# Is there something wrong with my post route?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

So I'm using sequelize for a simple CRUD style webpage.  My issue is I am able to send the data typed into an input field to mysql workbench and it's stored in the table but on the webpage itself nothing happens.

```js
  //uses var=Posts which contains the fields userName   
//and userPosts in my database
  var db = require("../models");
  
  // route to create posts
  app.post("/api/posts", function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    db.Posts.create({
      userName: req.body.username,
      userPosts: req.body.user_post,
    })
    .then(function(dbPost) {
      res.redirect('/dashboard');
      res.json(dbPost);
    });
  });
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: which js framework are you using? when is the then triggered? once you get a response?

Comment: I'm using node.js, handlebars, and sequelize.  I have the page redirected to the dashboard which is the homepage once the user hits submit after they type something. If I take the redirect out it takes me to a page that shows this:        {
"id": 7,
"userName": "2",
"userPosts": "asdf",
"createdAt": "2017-07-29T01:27:12.000Z",
"updatedAt": "2017-07-29T01:27:12.000Z"
}

Comment: Try taking out the redirect and see if it displays that.

Comment: Yeah sorry I meant to add that's what shows if I take redirect out.  Edited it now for clarity.

Comment: Once you've redirected, you're doing another request to the server for `/dashboard` and any output would have to be handled in the route for that URL

Answer (score 0):

> webpage itself nothing happens

What page? Your successful db action is telling the app to redirect to `/dashboard` but you're also trying to send JSON data. I'm surprised you're not getting header errors in your app. You can't redirect to another route and send data to the client at the same time.

You would need to redirect to `/dashboard` and then your dashboard route would have to query the data again to be returned for display.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity I'm really new to this. The page I'm talking about is the dashboard where the post should be displayed.  I see what you mean now though on how redirecting it and sending JSON data to it won't work. Could I just move the redirect before the dbPosts.create?

Comment: No, your route would redirect the client and fail to add your data to the store. Your api/posts POST route needs to only save the data, then redirect on success. Your dashboard GET route needs to then query your posts model (by username of course) and then display the results. 1 route = 1 action.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you both issue a `res.redirect()` at the same time as doing `res.json()`. Pick one of them.